# Internship in Germany for recent US university graduate, visa?

Tags: germany

I'm a US citizen who just received an offer for a paid internship that has potential to turn into a full-time position later on (for now, the internship duration will be 3 months). Though it is an internship, since I am no longer an actual student, do I just apply for a normal, general employment visa or is there another visa I need to apply for?

Also, do I need to be registered at a residence (Anmeldung) before I apply for the visa (I'm already staying in Berlin)?

Comment: Flagged for migration to Expats.

Comment: Regarding the second question, you have a few days for registration after moving into the residence; generally it is done in person at the city hall. The registration requirement is for people who live in Germany, independent of the visa requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do your Anmeldung before applying for the visa. Your rent contract and [Wohnungsgeberbestätigung](https://allaboutberlin.com/docs/wohnungsgeberbestatigung) are enough. This is true for the freelance visa, the work visa and the Blue Card at the Berlin Ausländerbehörde as of 2019.

Answer (score 1):

As a US citizen you can apply directly for the residence and work permit at the Ausländerbehörde.

Once you have the **Wohnunggeberbescheinigung** (**§19(3)**) apply for an online appointment to register.

Once you have moved in, you must register within 2 weeks (**§ 17(1)**).

With the appointment you fulfill the reporting conditions , since the waiting time is horrendous (up to 4-6 weeks).

> > Also, do I need to be registered at a residence (Anmeldung) before I apply for the visa?

If you already moved in, yes

- at least the date of the appointment application

One criteria for issuing a residence permit is whether the applicant will obey the law

- not doing so would give a bad impression

---

**Federal Act on Registration of 3 May 2013**

> **Chapter 3
>
>   General registration requirements
>
>   Section 17
>
>   Registration, deregistration**
>   1) Anyone who moves into a residence shall register with the registration authorities within **two weeks** of moving in.
>   ...
>   **Section 19
>
>   Cooperation by the supplier of the residence**
>   (1) The person supplying the residence **shall be obligated to cooperate with registration**. The person supplying the residence or someone authorized by him or her shall confirm in writing or pursuant to subsection 4 electronically within the period given in Section 17 (1) that the person required to register has moved in. He or she may contact the registration authority to find out whether the person required to register has done so. The person required to register shall provide the person supplying the residence with the information necessary to confirm that the former has moved in. Confirmation pursuant to the second sentence may be provided only by the person supplying the residence or someone authorized by him or her.
>   ...
>   (3) The **confirmation of the person supplying the residence** shall contain the following data:
>
> > 1. name and address of the person supplying the residence and name of the owner, if different,
> > 2. date moved in,
> > 3. address of the residence, and
> > 4. names of the persons required to register pursuant to Section 17 (1).
>
> ...

---

**Sources**:

- [Federal Act on Registration](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/index.html)